# c++ cant use functions of .h header file

Tags: c++

suddenly i couldnt use the new function i wrote which in .h header file and the old functions which i wrote i can use it, i cant believe that :S

**stdafx.h**

```
#include "function.h"
```

**Hook.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

    namespace DragoN_Hook
    {
            void EditOrginalCastleWar(int StartHour,int EndHour){

            unsigned char lol[4] = {0x83, 0x7A, 0x08,(unsigned char)StartHour};
            MemoryCopy((DWORD)0x00411A05,(DWORD)&lol,4);

    }
}
```

**function.h**

```
LPVOID MemoryCopy(DWORD destination, DWORD source, int length);
```

**function.cpp**

```
LPVOID MemoryCopy(DWORD destination, DWORD source, int length)
{
    DWORD oldSource      = 0;
    DWORD oldDestination = 0;

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)source,length,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&oldSource);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)destination,length,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&oldDestination);

    memcpy((void*)destination,(void*)source,length);

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)destination,length,oldDestination,&oldDestination);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)source,length,oldSource,&oldSource);

    return (LPVOID)destination;
};
```

**Error**
**error C3861: 'MemoryCopy': identifier not found**

Comment: If you put `#include "function.h"` in Hook.h, does the same thing happen. Also, is `stdafx.h` a precompiled header?

Comment: no it working if i put it in hook.h

Comment: See @rerun's answer, it's likely that your precompiled header isn't being recompiled. TBH, just disable them, they're not worth it for a project of this size.

Answer (score 2):

This happens usually when you compile and individual file which does not cause the precomplied header to be rebuilt. If you rebuild the solution it will recreate the header.  You can also turn off precompled headers and not have to deal with it.

Comment: how i can  turn off precompled

Comment: right click on the project Configuration Properties/"c/C++"/Precomplied Headers set Precompled Header to = Not Using Precomplied Headers